# gridview default sortexpression

Tags: asp.net, gridview-sorting

Has anyone managed to extend a GridView with default sorting?
This seems pretty trivial to me but i can't get it done.

The idea is to add a property `DefaultSortExpression` to a Server Control that inherits GridView.

- Calling Sort() performs an additional select, we don't want that.
- Setting `this.SelectArguments.SortExpression` seems to get it's value set after i do so that doesn't work either. (Unless there's some magical event i didn't try yet).

I want to be able to set the SortExpression before the GridView does it's databinding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected override DataSourceSelectArguments CreateDataSourceSelectArguments()
        {
            DataSourceSelectArguments dsa = base.CreateDataSourceSelectArguments();

            // dsa.SortExpression = "my field";

           return dsa;
}
```